# How to use msinfo32.exe command lines in a Process?

Tags: c#, windows

I have this simple code:

```
private void MsInfo()
        {
            Process proc = new Process();
            proc.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
            proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            proc.StartInfo.FileName = "msinfo32.exe";
            proc.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            proc.StartInfo.Arguments = "/nfo " + contentDirectory + "\\msinfo.nfo";
            proc.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = contentDirectory;
            proc.Start();
            proc.WaitForExit();
            proc.Close();
        }
```

I want to create msinfo.nfo in the directory contentDirectory.
The contentDirectory now is:

C:\Users\bout0_000\AppData\Local\Diagnostic_Tool_Blue_Screen\Diagnostic Tool Blue Screen\SF_28-07-13

The reason i want to use variable contentDirectory in the arguments is that the directory SF_28-07-13 change every day. Tommorow it will be SF_29-07-13

If i will do in the arguments:

proc.StartInfo.Arguments = "/nfo C:\TEST\TEST.NFO" then the file TEST.NFO will be created in C:\TEST

But for some reason when im using the contentDirectory variable i cant see the file msinfo.nfo anywhere.

Instead i see a strange file name called Diagnostic in the location of:

C:\Users\bout0_000\AppData\Local\Diagnostic_Tool_Blue_Screen
Two directories back from the contentDirectory

The Diagnostic file is 24mb and its ok but thats not the file name i wanted to create and not in this location.

I tried many ways in the Arguments and also removed/deleted the line : `proc.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = contentDirectory;`

But nothing worked.

What else can i do ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the string of

```
C:\Users\bout0_000\AppData\Local\Diagnostic_Tool_Blue_Screen\Diagnostic Tool Blue Screen\SF_28-07-13\msinfo.nfo
```

should be in double quotes:

```
"C:\Users\bout0_000\AppData\Local\Diagnostic_Tool_Blue_Screen\Diagnostic Tool Blue Screen\SF_28-07-13\msinfo.nfo"
```

with:

```
proc.StartInfo.Arguments = "/nfo " + "\"" + contentDirectory + "\\msinfo.nfo" + "\"";
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need at all the full path for the Arguments property.
You already set the WorkingDirectory to `contentDirectory` thus, the file nfo, will be created there automatically.

```
 proc.StartInfo.Arguments = "/nfo msinfo.nfo";
 proc.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = contentDirectory;
```

It is like you are at the command prompt and you type a

```
C:>\ CD "\Users\bout0_000\AppData\Local\Diagnostic_Tool_Blue_Screen\Diagnostic Tool Blue Screen\SF_28-07-13"
C:\Users\bout0_000\AppData\Local\Diagnostic_Tool_Blue_Screen\Diagnostic Tool Blue Screen\SF_28-07-13> msinfo32.exe /nfo msinfo.nfo
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are setting the working directory, you can leave off the path the output file and the file should be created relative to the working directory:

```
proc.StartInfo.Arguments = "/nfo msinfo.nfo";
proc.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = contentDirectory;
```

But, in general, paths of any kind should be quoted when placed into a space-separated string because they are single items. So:

```
proc.StartInfo.Arguments = "/nfo \"msinfo.nfo\"";
proc.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = contentDirectory;
```